# SQL Query to exclude record on certain criteria

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I have a situation, where my table have records and I want to extract data from it on the basis of what item I have w.r.t the group and class.
Below is a screen shot, First part is the records in table and second one is how I want to extract data.
For ID(s) if I have a same Class and Group but for item field, on one record I have ud9 and for other it's blank, then I have always have to pic the one with item.
I can get it by `select distinct ID,Class,Group,item from MyTable
where ID='A001' and item<>''`

but I also need other lines, how can I get other lines?
and must not get the second line for A001 with same class and group without item.

[image]

Comment: wich version of sql server do you use?

Comment: I don't like getting negative points and what to what's wrong with this question so someone come and say -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of solutions:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      ID CHAR(4) ,
      Class CHAR(1) ,
      gr CHAR(2) ,
      Item CHAR(3)
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'A001', 'A', 'A1', 'ud9' ),
        ( 'A001', 'A', 'A1', '' ),
        ( 'A001', 'B', '', 'ud4' ),
        ( 'A001', 'B', '', '' ),
        ( 'A001', 'D', 'D2', '' ),
        ( 'A002', 'A', 'A1', '' );

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID, Class, gr ORDER BY CASE
                                                              WHEN item = ''
                                                              THEN 1
                                                              ELSE 0
                                                              END ) AS rn,
                        COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID, Class, gr) AS cn
               FROM     @t
             )
SELECT  ID, Class, gr, Item
FROM    cte
WHERE   rn = 1 OR cn = 1
```

Output:

```
ID  Class   gr  Item
A001    A   A1  ud9
A001    B       ud4
A001    D   D2     
A002    A   A1
```

Your query wiil look like:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID, Class, Group ORDER BY CASE
                                                              WHEN item = ''
                                                              THEN 1
                                                              ELSE 0
                                                              END ) AS rn,
                        COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID, Class, gr) AS cn
               FROM     MyTable
             )
SELECT  ID, Class, Group, Item
FROM    cte
WHERE   rn = 1 OR cn = 1
```

Comment: I don't want to use temp tables, it would be a kind of dynamics process, user is calculating amount for item on the basis of IDs, there could be new ids added in table so each time user click calculate I need to recalculate amounts and for this need to read records from MyTable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT ID,
       Class,
       [Group],
       item
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY ID, Class, [Group]
                   ORDER BY CASE WHEN item='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) rn,
               *
        FROM   MyTable)a
WHERE  rn = 1
```

If you have more than one `item` per `ID`, `Class` and `Group` then use this

```
SELECT ID,
       Class,
       [Group],
       item
FROM   (SELECT *,
               CASE WHEN item = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   temp,
               Count(1)OVER(partition BY ID, Class, [Group]) cnt
        FROM   MyTable)a
WHERE  temp = 0
        OR cnt = 1
```

Comment: If I run whole query it gives no result, but below part work perfectly.

Comment: SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY ID, Class, [Group]
                   ORDER BY CASE WHEN item='' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) rn,
               *
        FROM   MyTable

Answer (score 1):

Two criteria, either item is blank or count is 1, try this:

```
select distinct * from table1 t1 where item <> '' OR
(select count(*) from table1 t2 where t1.id=t2.id and 
 t1.class=t2.class and t1.groups=t2.groups) = 1
```